# Hide value in Html.textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

A little question but I didn't find an answer, is it possible to pass and default hidden value in textbox ?

Explanation : So I have this piece of code :

```
@Html.TextBox("date", null, new { @class = "date" ,@Value =DateTime.Today.Date.Month})
```

In `@Value`, I'm putting a default value ( the month of the current date ) but I'd like this value not to be seen by the user ! I have tried to add a `@Hidden = true` but, as I expected, it's hidding the text box not the value.

So is there a way to only hide the value ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: No, that is not possble. You'll need an additional hidden field, or some other mechanism.

Comment: What would be the point of doing that. And never set the `value` attribute when using a `HtmlHelper` method. You set the value of the property in the controller before you pass it to the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's because I'm using this textbox for a javascript date picker and when I'm not seeting a Value, it's putting 01-01-0001 in the text box (still have problems with this ... datepicker)

Comment: @PeterB Ok thank you !  I will find an other way then !

Comment: @MrPixel6, That has nothing to do with it :) You set the value of `date` in the controller, but since its a `DateTime`, trying to assign a `int` (the Month) could never work anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are right ^^ But I'm so desperate with those dates that I'm trying to do anything to make them work :p

Comment: Then perhaps you need to ask a question about the datepicker issue showing the relevant code/script and explain whats not working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to populate textbox with today's date by writing.

$(.date).daterangepicker({ minDate: new Date() });

It wont require any changes in textbox helper.

so it will not show you date like '01-01-0001' any more.
Hope this works.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set some attribute like defaultValue in input tag and than when you submit your form check if any value in that input than pass that value otherwise you can pass default value.

```
@Html.TextBox("date", null, new { @class = "date" ,DefaultValue =DateTime.Today.Date.Month})
```

javascript:when you submit the value first check this and set your value

```
if($('#date').val()=="")
{
    $('#date').val($('#date').attr('DefaultValue'));
}
```